C# TcpClient Networkstream read timeout - Recognize a String from ReadAsync (Telnet)
I am connecting to a remote Telnet Server using TcpClient and Networkstream, as long as the expected answer is delivered from the server everything works fine - however I would like to add a timeout, to catch an exception.
That's my current code, where I am waiting for "Username"
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

string response = "";
int bytesRead;

var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(5000); //does not work as timeout

while (!response.Contains("Username"))
{
    try
    {
        bytesRead = await targetClient.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        response += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Console.WriteLine($"Answer from Telnet-Server: {response}");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("catch");
        break;
    }
}

If I understand the ReadAsync function right - the cancellationToken is not taken into Account - so that's not how a timeout could be added.
Is there any possibility to add a timeout? Maybe some second Workerthread, which fires after 5 Seconds, and if the response does not contain "Username" I break out of the while loop?
Or should I change the ReadAsync do a Synchronous Method, which supports a timeout?
Or should I read everything from the Telnet Server into a Queue, and only ask if the Queue contains a relevant keyword, like "Username", would that be possible?
But I think there are much better approaches, right?
Thanks

"If I understand the ReadAsync function right - the cancellationToken is not taken into Account - so that's not how a timeout could be added." no it should work. Are you perhaps blocking somewhere with .Wait or .Result?

Thanks for you comment - could you please take a look at this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24093 - Maybe I am misinterpreting the behaviour.
No I don't have a .Wait oder .Result, if I debug the application, the application is stuck inside .ReadAsync Method

I believe this is now fixed https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/36516 although you haven't said which version of .NET you are using

I don't really know if this approach is OK, but it's working. Any comments if there are any pitfalls?
static async Task<string> WaitForPromptAsync(NetworkStream stream, string prompt, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    while (DateTime.Now - startTime < timeout)
    {
        if (stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            response.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
           
            if (response.ToString().Contains(prompt))
            {
                return response.ToString();
            }
        }

        await Task.Delay(100); // is that OK?
    }

    return response.ToString();
}

vor example:
receivedData = await WaitForPromptAsync(stream, "Username", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
if (receivedData.Contains("Username"))
{ //do something
}
else
{ //timeout occured
}


This is still going to block waiting for the read if there is no data. And the Task.Delay seems pointless. Note that you have a fundamental issue here: you assume that the prompt will be contained in a single read. Multiple reads or writes can be combined or split into multiple packets, and received separately or together at the other end. You need proper message framing.
